# regex: matching 3 consecutive words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to see if a string contains 3 consecutive words (divided by spaces and without numbers), but the regex I have constructed does not seem to work:

```
print re.match('([a-zA-Z]+\b){3}', "123 test bla foo")
None
```

This should return true since the string contains the 3 words "test bla foo".

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: As a side note: use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()` - the latter would start from the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do:

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+ ){2}[A-Za-z]+
```

- `(?:[A-Za-z]+ ){2}`: the non-captured group `(?:[A-Za-z]+ )` matches one or more alphabetic characters followed by space, `{2}` matches two such successive groups
- `[A-Za-z]+` matches one or more alphabetic character after the preceding two words, making the third word

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8LDW9v/1)

If you want the words to be separated by any whitespace instead of just space:

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+\s){2}[A-Za-z]+
```

Comment: Thanks heemayl, this works. I'm just trying to understand why something like this won't work `(?:[A-Za-z]+[\s\b]){3}` as well

Comment: @Subbeh That needs a whitespace after the third word too.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to select the first words of a string:

```
^(?:[^\ ]+\ ){3}
```

I use the whitespaces for define and delimite each words.

`[^\ ]+`: minimum one char except whitespaces, followed by an whitespace `\`.
After you juste have to enter the number of words you want : `{3}`

It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

this is a much better option.
 It includes words with hyphens or apostrophe, like "don't" or "mother-in-law"

```
([^\s]+ ){2}[^\s]+
```