# regex for 3 consecutive words if there are any

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for regex that extract 3 consecutive words if there are any.
For example, if I have 2 strings:

```
"1. Stack is great and awesome"
"2. Stack"
```

The result is:

```
"Stack is great"
"Stack"
```

This answer doesn't work for me: [regex: matching 3 consecutive words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688781/regex-matching-3-consecutive-words)

My effort:

```
(?:[A-ZŠČĆŽa-zščćž]+ )(?:[A-ZŠČĆŽa-zščćž]+ )(?:[A-ZŠČĆŽa-zščćž]+ )
```

Comment: You need [`[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+){0,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/omKcW7/1). But in order to use it correctly, you need appropriate code. Do you need a single match from any string or multiple? You seem to need a full Unicode support.

Comment: What about that other post didn't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
> x <- c("1. Stack is great and awesome", "2. Stack")
> regmatches(x, regexpr("[A-Za-z]+(?:\\s+[A-Za-z]+){0,2}", x))
[1] "Stack is great" "Stack"
## Or to support all Unicode letters
> y <- c("1. Stąck is great and awesome", "2. Stack")
> regmatches(y, regexpr("\\p{L}+(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}", y, perl=TRUE))
[1] "Stąck is great" "Stack"
## In some R environments, it makes sense to use another, TRE, regex:
> regmatches(y, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+(?:[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+){0,2}", x))
[1] "Stąck is great" "Stack"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/daQAJ4/3) and the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/n4svSm) and an alternative [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/daQAJ4/2).

Note that the regex will extract the first chunk of 1, 2 or 3 letter words from any string. If you need at least 2 words, replace `{0,2}` limiting quantifier with `{1,2}` one.

To extract multiple matches, use `gregexpr` rather than `regexpr`.

**Pattern details**

- `\\p{L}+` / `[A-Za-z]` - any 1+ Unicode (or  ASCII if `[A-Za-z]` is used) letters
- `(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}` / `(?:\\s+[a-zA-Z]+){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 consecutive occurrences of:

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\\p{L}+` / `[A-Za-z]` - any 1+ Unicode (or  ASCII if `[A-Za-z]` is used) letters

Mind using the `perl=TRUE` argument with the regex that uses `\p{L}` construct. If it does not work, try adding the `(*UCP)` PCRE verb at the very beginning of the pattern that makes the all generic/Unicode/shorthand classes really Unicode aware.

Note that all these regexps will work with `stringr::str_extract` and `stringr::str_extract_all`:

```
> str_extract(x, "\\p{L}+(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}")
[1] "Stack is great" "Stack"         
> str_extract(x, "[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\s+[a-zA-Z]+){0,2}")
[1] "Stack is great" "Stack"         
> str_extract(x, "[[:alpha:]]+(?:\\s+[[:alpha:]]+){0,2}")
[1] "Stack is great" "Stack"
```

There is no support for `(*UCP)` here as `stringr` functions are ICU regex powered, not PCRE. Unicode test:

```
> str_extract(y, "\\p{L}+(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}")
[1] "Stąck iç great" "Stack"         
> str_extract(y, "[[:alpha:]]+(?:\\s+[[:alpha:]]+){0,2}")
[1] "Stąck iç great" "Stack"
```

Comment: @Mislav OK, I will also add that one to the current two.

Comment: `(*UCP)` changes only `\d \D \s \S \w \W \b \B`, but `\p{L}` (and other `\p{xx}`)  are always the same (with or without `(*UCP)`). You can remove it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte If the library was not compiled with the PCRE_UCP flag, isn't it required then? Well, thos R versions I have access to now really work without `(*UCP)`, but I remember older versions that didn't. Ok, let's correct it and leave a note.

Comment: The PCRE_UCP flag sets only a default behaviour, but doesn't change the `\p{xx}` classes (nor `\h` or `\v` that already contain unicode characters).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ok, anyway, in my Windows R 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) neither `"\\p{L}+(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}"` nor `"(*UCP)\\p{L}+(?:\\s+\\p{L}+){0,2}"` work, only an `[[:alpha:]]` based pattern works with Unicode correctly.